# Json.Net deserialize from camel notation to standard .Net property notation (without attributes)

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I'm receiving serialized Json where all fields are named using camel notation like:

```
"removeExecutedAfter":"2013-09-29T00:00:00.000+04:00"}
```

I want to deserialize this Json into .Net properties using standard notation like (Json.Net is being used):

```
Public DateTime RemoveExecutedAfter {get; set;}
```

I don't want to use [JsonProperty(PropertyName="removeExecutedAfter")] attribute since its a lot of rather tedious work.

How to control serialization/deserialization in Json.Net this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json .NET should be case insensitive by default.

The following hacky test works

```
public class Test
{
    public DateTime RemoveExecutedAfter {get; set;}
}
```

The test

```
var json = "{\"removeExecutedAfter\":\"2013-09-29T00:00:00.000+04:00\"}";
var jsonNetSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create();
var des = jsonNetSerializer.Deserialize<Test>(new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json))); // RemoveExecutedAfter is set to the correct date
```

Comment: You can just do `var des = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(json);`.

Comment: Thank you. I have no idea why it has not worked for me before.